# apt-get 'deb' is not known in /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: apt, rpm, deb, tinycore

I get following error trying to excute apt-get update

> 'deb' is not known in /etc/apt/sources.list

My sources.list

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stable/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stable/updates main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
```

I looked in various forums but couldn't find a solution for it. It's not a typo.

The output of

```
hex -C /etc/apt/sources.list
```

doesn't show anything suspicious. Am I missing some configuration for apt?

I use tiny Core Linux 8.0 and installed apt via rpm

Comment: I'm assuming this is a new install of Stretch, right? Resist the urge to post for help without providing a single bit of meaningful data about the system, how old it is, if it's been upgraded from previous steble, etc? How do you expect anyone to help you?

Comment: I use tiny core and want to use apt

Comment: Then update your post and provide the data that people need to help you!! Don't expect people to be psychic, to be able to intuit by feel what you actually are running. Provide the basics required, what is the hardware, cpu type, exact version of gnu/linux running it, etc.

Comment: You're confusing concepts here, you got tinycore to have a tiny install image, not to run apt packages. I wish I had more downvotes to give, but 1 is all I get.

Comment: Why i am confusing concepts ? Some people maybe need more recent Software then provided from tc mirrors. dCore is the Same apporach . If you feel happy to downvote a question you not have added some useful answer.. go ahead...

Comment: You earned the downvote by not providing a single bit of relevant data, there's still not a word about the hardware you're running for example. You're confusing the purpose of downvotes, that's for when questions are bad, and with little to no value, not a situation where one would want to provide an answer.

Comment: I Run it on a Intel Atom your answer was Not helpful either just some Info about tc manager. Anyway I dont See any issue running apt on tc, in fact it offers alot of opportunities .

Comment: That’s a rather obscure error message which basically means the “deb” type hasn’t been registered with the version of `apt` you’re using. Presumably there’s some other type you need to use with whatever version of `apt` you have... Either that, or this is simply an instance of the general principle that you can’t mix and match package managers; you should only use the package manager that your distribution is designed to use.

Comment: Oh, and while `apt` may have been adapted to run on tiny core, I *very* much doubt that the standard Debian repositories’ packages will work on tiny core. Could you [edit] your question to clarify exactly how you installed `apt`, and where you got it from?

Comment: The notion that you can pop in a full stretch distribution into tinycore, lol, when it's clearly designed to be a hyper lean ultra minimalistic linux system using tiny light  http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/concepts.html packages. Clearly the wrong distribution was chosen, with no understanding of why it was chosen. It ships with busybox I believe, and there are I'm sure proper ways to add programs to it, which can be learned. Debian stretch will run fine on Atom, why not pick the right distro, and run Debian? Simple install.

Comment: http://wiki.tinycorelinux.net/dcore:welcome

Answer (score 0):

Since you’re using dCore, you should use the SCE Tools to install software, not `apt` directly. The SCE Tools know how to retrieve packages from the appropriate Debian release, and how to convert them to the package format used in dCore.